# Mashery Quotas: Calls per "day" or calls per "24-hours"?

Tags: mashery

I am accessing an API hosted by Mashery with the following rate limit:

- 5 calls per second
- 10,000 calls per day

Does that imply that I can make 10,000 requests at 6:00PM, and then make another 10,000 requests at midnight?  Or, does it mean I can only make 10,000 requests within any 24-hour period?

For example, does it mean that if I make 10,000 requests between 6:00PM one day, and 6:00PM the next, that I have to wait until 6:00:01PM before I can make another request.  And then, at most I can make requests at the same rate I made the day prior (as the 24-hour period continuously shifts)?

I apologize if this is off-topic.  I have a support request in for clarification, but I don't think they'll get back to me any time soon, and I figured that someone here would be familiar with the limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is set per Calendar date and resets every midnight GMT time.
So for example if you made 10,000 calls at 6pm pacific (which is 2am GMT) you would have to wait 22 hours until 4pm pacific (which is midnight GMT) until you can start using your next batch of 10,000 daily calls.

Hope that answers your question.

Thanks,

Shai Simchi
Mashery Customer Support

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  That's what I call some proactive customer support.